# Highest salary per department (also same salary)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

How can I select the highest salary on each department with a same salary.

My query is only to get the first row in each department with the same salary. But I want to select all max same salary on each department. Please help me out of this problem.

Below is the sample table:

```
PSD Department
----------------------
Yumang's Salary: $500
Paus Salary: $500

QA Department
----------------------
Villanueva: $1000 
Calacar: $1000
```

Here's the code I am trying:

```
SELECT MAX(inter_department_votes.number_votes)
FROM employee_salary
GROUP BY dept_id
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAX function used with GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350829/max-function-used-with-group-by-clause)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer may depend on the dbms used.)

Comment: @jarlh SQL SERVER, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try selecting dept_id as well:

```
SELECT dept_id, 
       MAX(inter_department_votes.number_votes) 
FROM employee_salary GROUP BY dept_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RANK()` function:

RANK provides the same numeric value for ties (for example 1, 1, 2, 4, 5).

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT dept_id, 
             PersonName, 
             Salary,
             RANK() OVER(PARTITION dept_id ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS SortBySalary 
      FROM employee_salary
     )
WHERE SortBySalary = 1
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34350888/327165) using `MAX()` function.

Comment: Prashant Pimpale: Edits should be significant.

Answer (score 0):

your table isn't clear to me. i can't understand why you're creating separate tables for all departments.

assuming you make two different tables, one for employees and one for department. this will make queries simpler for future and efficient database. In that case:

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+
|EmployeeID|EmployeeName|Salary|DepNo|
+----------+------------+------+-----+
|                                    |
+----------+------------+------+-----+
+-----+-------+
|DepNo|DepName|
+-----+-------+
|             |
+-----+-------+


 SELECT DepName, EmployeeName, salary
 FROM Department d
 INNER JOIN Employee e on e.DepNo = d.DepNo 
 INNER JOIN 
 (
    SELECT DepNo, MAX(salary) sal
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY DepNo
 ) ss ON e.DepNo = ss.DepNo
 AND e.salary = ss.sal;
```